# Rows in a rack configuration

Tags: datacenter

I am new to these terminologies in a data center.
Can someone explain how many rows can be present in a rack?

Comment: @KonradGajewski super helpful.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/server_rack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A chassis is a computer case, typically which is populated with computer components, like a wiring harness, motherboard, disks, power supplies, etc.  Although sometimes a chassis has slots for multiple motherboards.  Usually you'd buy a server assembled, but you can buy parts (which hopefully match) and get a naked chassis.

A rack is a frame, like a closet on wheels (and feet) and maybe doors and sides.  A rack can be two pole (like a network rack, without sides) or four pole.  The "poles" are tall square brackets with supports to keep it rigid and holes for mounting hardware to hang multiple chassis in the rack.  Network hardware and PDUs typically have "ears" to mount them into a two or four pole rack.  Server chassis usually come with rails  which attach to the four poles and then you slide the server into the rails.

Comment: Might be worth adding that "rows" in this context usually refers to rows of racks (cabinets), separated by hot and cold aisles. Each rack is organized in rack units of 44 mm height (standard: 42u or 43u per rack) and a certain depth. Each component uses one or more of those units.

Comment: question was completely changed after I answered rather than asking a new question.  I don't see a point in re-answering, they might just change their question again.